# MYSQL - select from part of table to reduce search time

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql db that has hundreds of thousands of rows.  I want to search for a term in one of the fields but only in the last 10000 rows.  Searching the entire table takes entirely too long, and it is unlikely the results I am looking for will be older than last 10000 rows.  Is there a way to craft a query like the following:

```
 SELECT body from <last 10000 rows of table> where body like '%searchTerm%'
```

Comment: You might wanna take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Short answer: no, what you suggest is not possible. The reason is that there is not clearly defined part or section of the table holding 1000 rows. The data in the table is not ordered, so you'd have to run a selection query first to be able to define that "part of the table", then to query it. This can be done in a single step using a subquery, or in two steps using a temporary table, even by means of a view. But if this spears the search up or even slows it down is something hard to say. You will have to try...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the LIMIT clause in mysql, but in order to tell what is the last columns, you must also have an ORDER clause.

Like the following

```
SELECT `body` FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `dateOfRelevance` DESC LIMIT 10000) a WHERE `body` LIKE '%searchTerm%'
```

Though I am not sure mysql will be able to properly utilize an INDEX on `body`

Comment: To answer your index question: no, MySQL can't use an index to satisfy a `LIKE` query with a leading wildcard.

Answer (score -1):

Your search will not be able to use an index because of the leading wildcard, so that will always be expensive. As you pointed out, you can avoid a full table scan by isolating a subset of rows, and then doing the scan on those rows.

Depending on your schema and indexes there are multiple ways to isolate a subset of rows.

Assuming you have an auto-increment primary key on your table, you can use that to select the most recent rows and limit the scan to those rows. Whether you can limit it to exactly 10000 rows is difficult if your auto-increment PK has gaps in it, but this approach should help you get started.

For example:

```
SELECT body 
from your_table
where id > (select (max(id) - 10000) from your_table)
and body like '%searchTerm%'
```

If that doesn't work for you there are other ways to isolate a subset of rows. For example if you have an indexed temporal column you could use that to search recent record, for example search any records created in the past 7 days:

```
SELECT body 
from your_table
where created_at > current_date() - interval 7 day
and body like '%searchTerm%'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT body from <last 10000 rows of table> where body like '%searchTerm%'
```

you need something like this?

```
SELECT body from table where body like '%searchTerm%' order by id desc limit 10000
```

Comment: This will return something else (10k results, instead of the results from the first 10k) and will still search all rows, then order, then only send a part. So i'm afraid it would not do what the OP asks.

Comment: @Nanne Technically correct (i did not understand the search only last 10k records for speed) -> that's something like nested selects `SELECT body from (SELECT body from table order by id desc limit 10000) where body like '%searchTerm%'` - Thank you !